# Game Maker: Cómo logro este efecto?

Tags: objeto, game

Quiero que cuando mi personaje se posicione detrás de un objeto, el sprite del objeto quede en frente de el y cuando se posicione en frente, el sprite del objeto quede detrás

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Recuerdo ver esto una vez en un taller... Ese sprite en realidad está cortado, por lo que eso crea el efecto de estar delante o detras.

Comment: https://forum.yoyogames.com/index.php?threads/solved-depth-and-drawing-sprites.28800/

Answer (score 0):

puedes probar con depth =  -y;

para ello, debes configurar el  pivote de cada sprite en la parte inferior.
Eso hace que el  objeto se coloque por detrás de otro cuando la posición y  sea menor (Esté mas arriba).. Otorgandole un efecto de profundidad.. util para los juegos rpg

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/352813)

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).